# R: Distribution of Random Samples vs. 1 Random Sample

Tags: r, random, montecarlo, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have a question about random sampling.

Are the two following results (A and B) statistically the same?

```
nobs <- 1000

A <- rt(n=nobs, df=3, ncp=0)

simulations <- 50
B <- unlist(lapply(rep.int(nobs/simulations, times=simulations),function(y) rt(n=y, df=3, ncp=0) ))
```

I thought it would be but now I've been going back and forth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some small changes, you can even make them numerically equal. You only need to seed the RNG and omit specifying the `ncp` parameter and use the default value (of 0) instead:

```
nobs <- 1000
set.seed(42)
A <- rt(n=nobs, df=3)

simulations <- 50
set.seed(42)
B <- unlist(lapply(rep.int(nobs/simulations, times=simulations),function(y) rt(n=y, df=3) ))

all.equal(A, B)
#[1] TRUE
```

Why don't you get equal results when you specify `ncp=0`?

Because then `rt` assumes that you actually want a non-central t-distribution and the values are calculated with `rnorm(n, ncp)/sqrt(rchisq(n, df)/df)`. That means when creating 1000 values at once `rnorm` is called once and `rchisq` is called once subsequently. If you create 50 times 20 values, you have alternating calls to these RNGs, which means the RNG states are different for the `rnorm` and `rchisq` calls than in the first case.